# pattern matching for String having "{"

Tags: java, regex

First I did this -

```
String str = "{\"hits\":[{\"links_count\":6,\"forum_count\":11}],\"totalHitCount\":1}";

        Assert.assertTrue(str.matches("{\"hits\":[{\"links_count\":[0-9]{1,},\"forum_count   \":11}],\"totalHitCount\":[0-9]{1,}}"),
            "Partnership message does not appear");
```

This got me following error -

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
{"hits":[\{"links_count":[0-9]{1,},"forum_count":11}],"totalHitCount":[0-9]{1,}}
```

Then I did (escapes the "{") -

```
String str = "\\{\"hits\":[\\{\"links_count\":6,\"forum_count\":11\\}],\"totalHitCount\":1\\}";

    Assert.assertTrue(str.matches("\\{\"hits\":[\\{\"links_count\":[0-9]{1,},\"forum_count\":11\\}],\"totalHitCount\":[0-9]{1,}\\}"),
            "Partnership message does not appear");
```

and got the the following error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Partnership message does not appear expected:<true> but was:<false>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to escape `{`  `[` in your input. But you need to escape `[` `]` in your regex.

Try this:

```
String str = "{\"hits\":[{\"links_count\":6,\"forum_count\":11}],\"totalHitCount\":1}";

System.out.println(str.matches("\\{\"hits\":\\[\\{\"links_count\":[0-9]{1,},\"forum_count\":11\\}\\],\"totalHitCount\":[0-9]{1,}\\}"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You're correct in escaping the curly braces within your regular expression (the string inside `matches("...")`), as otherwise they get interpreted as pattern repetition.

You should not, however, escape the curly braces inside `str` itself, as that'll only break things in your case.

There is this nice [online tool](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm) which you may find useful in debugging Java regular expression.

Answer (score 3):

The correct regexp is:

```
str.matches("\\{\"hits\":\\[\\{\"links_count\":[0-9]+,\"forum_count\":[0-9]+\\}\\],\"totalHitCount\":[0-9]+\\}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the Square brackets []

```
String str = "{\"hits\":[{\"links_count\":6,\"forum_count\":11}],\"totalHitCount\":1}";
```

This will return true

```
Assert.assertTrue(str.matches("\\{\"hits\":\\[\\{\"links_count\":[0-9]{1,},\"forum_count\":11\\}\\],\"totalHitCount\":[0-9]{1,}\\}"),"Partnership message does not appear");
```